# php tag system - if tag already exists in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags, codeigniter-3

i am establisihing a tags system and don't want a tag in the tags table  to be added if it already exists. For this,  do i need to select and verify a table with additional query, or can i do the both with one query ?

```
 if (isset($tag_array)) {
    foreach ($tag_array as $tag_name) {
    $data = array('tag_id' => '', 'name' => $tag_name, 'slug' => '');

    $str = $this->db->insert_string('tags', $data);
    $this->db->query($str);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database can handle this.  Create a unique constraint on the tag name:

```
alter table tags add constraint unq_tags_tagname unique tags(tagname)
```

Your insert code will then generate an error if you attempt to insert the same name twice.